# Android SDK Manager fail to run after unfinished update

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-manager

why my SDK Manager fail to run when open in eclipse. Before this all work fine, until i update the component via SDK manager, then i accidentally close the sdk manager while it update. After that it cannot run and console through error.

Here the error:

[2014-12-11 08:34:16 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '-v' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

[2014-12-11 08:34:16 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.

[2014-12-11 08:34:17 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path

Any idea how to fix this.?

Answer (score 1):

The way I fixed the similar problem on my system (Windows 8.1, 64 bit, JDK 7) was:

1. Create JAVA_HOME environment variable and point it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin (You might have already done it)
2. Open ANDROID SDK DIRECTORY\tools\android.bat in your favourite text editor
3. Find the lines set java_exe= call lib\find_java.bat (it's split over 2 lines)
4. Replace the lines with set java_exe="%JAVA_HOME%\java.exe"
5. Save and run tools\android.bat

if problem persists
It might be due to incomplete changes in the sdk/tools/lib folder.
try replacing these [files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5aip5w2sqx8fqy/replace.rar?dl=0) at

> sdk root>/tools/lib

Comment: I  try step 1-5 not work, but the idea replacing the file make it work. I try replace with your file not working. The i replace whole tools\ folder with new sdk download tools\ folder. Then sdk manager run again and save my day. I just only need to download and update back again.